# How to debug through .NET Framework source code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

This question was asked before... but a while back.. and perhaps someone found a solution. Has anybody been able to debug through .NET Framework source code after installing VS 2008 SP1?
I can't get VS to download the source code (although I'm able to download .pbd files)

Comment: I get the same behavior ... it downloads the symbols (.pbd files) ... but doesn't let you step through source code. It says that no source code is available for this location ... no matter what stack frame I double click on.