# Monitoring changes of a private field in an external assembly without source

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I want to monitor (or place a breakpoint on) each change of a static field which is member of an internal class which resides in an external assembly for which I don't have code:

```
Assembly: PresentationCore.dll
Class   : MS.Internal.MemoryPressure
Field   : private static long _totalMemory
```

Ideally I should be able to see the stacktraces which trigger the changes.

Is this possible with VS and if yes then how do I have to setup VS in order to do this? Or will I need some external profiling tool?

Comment: You can possibly decompile it using smth like Reflector and then use VS to debug this. However, I'm not sure it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a breakpoint on a field.  You are in luck, there's only one method that modifies the value, called AddToTotal.  Debug + New Breakpoint + Break At Function.  Type "MS.Internal.MemoryPressure.AddToTotal" and untick the "Use IntelliSense" option.  The debugger will break as soon as the method is called, typically when the code creates a bitmap.  You will only have machine code to look at.

As soon as it breaks, you can add a watch for MS.Internal.MemoryPressure._totalMemory.  Adjust the breakpoint in the disassembly so it breaks past the field assignment.

Comment: The breakpoint got added and is visible in the Breakpoints window but the debugger does never stop there. (Just my code is already disabled)

Comment: Test it by adding an Image control to the window with a valid Source property value.  That reliably triggered the breakpoint when I tried it.  The field only tracks Milcore resources.

Comment: My app contains explicit calls to `WriteableBitmap.ctor(width, height, [..])` so this definitely should stop there. But I have to find out why this counter seems to be constantly >1MB (and so triggering `GC.Collect(2)` very often) maybe caused by some 3rd party component (Actipro, xceed, ...).

Comment: Having changed AnyCPU -> x86 at least this breakpoint stops (but still no PDBs for PresentationCore and PresentationFramework)

Answer (score 1):

Since PresentationCore is part of .Net you can [debug the framework source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx)
Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736820/how-to-debug-through-net-framework-source-code)

Comment: Ok, I can load symbols for a module but how do I then find the place where I want the debugger to stop?

Comment: The sources are there, on your computer (assuming you're using VS 2008/2010), you just have to find the right file, take a look at the question I've added link to

Comment: I have no luck: While symbols got loaded for most of the framework assemblies (System.Data.dll, System.Data.Entity.dll, etc.) they didn't for PresentationCore.dll: "Cannot find or open the PDB file" -- manually triggering "Loading Symbols from -> Microsoft Symbol servers" doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Both RedGate [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) as well as JetBrains [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can help you do it. They both decompile the assembly and generate the C# source code after which they allow you to work with it as if it were yours including placing breakpoints, watching the stack, etc.

I started with reflector, but now (starting from v.6) I switched to resharper it seems at this point to be more robust. Resharper has a 30 days trial, reflector used to be free I am not sure what it is now

Comment: R# was able to show/download the source but breakpoints don't hit (most likely because debugger still doesn't find pdbs for PresentationCore.dll). BTW: R# has a 30 days trial.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:
http://ayende.com/blog/4106/nhibernate-inotifypropertychanged